# the process cannot access the file web.config because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm working with ASP.NET Web form, I have an problem uncomfortable
is: When I debug the program and stop debugging, now I open the file  web.config and edit some thing, after edit, I click save, it throw an error like image below:

[image]

I must close the Visual Studio, and open again. Now save success. Is there any way to save and don't need to close Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you just terminate the local IIS server? There should be a symbol at the windows taskbar

Comment: @momo: I have been checked, I've been stopped all, I never seen this bug before, but today this bug begin existed.

Comment: @Hong Van Vit, Whether all web projects have the same issues? Whether there is just one web project in this solution? How about the result if you reset your VS settings?  As you said that you open the web.config file, do you use the VS to edit this file or other tools?

Comment: @Hong Van Vit, Not really debug your app, I mean that just run your app with "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", and then close the app, edit the config file, how about the result?

Comment: @Hong Van Vit, Do you resolve this issue in your side? If not, feel free to share the latest information here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (v16.2.0) and encountered the same problem. Turns out it is the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe` which locked the web.config. Close IIS Express won't fix it.

I ended up use `IObit Unlocker` to kill the grab.

Comment: I have the same problem...If I close the VS and try to modify from another text editor it's working...I also opened VS as administrator and no luck...